# Rails benchmark reports less time than activerecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to benchmark this query:

```
Person.where(age: 60)
```

When I run it in the console it says:

> Person Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."age" = ?  [["age", 60]]

When I benchmark it, it reports 0.17ms

```
def self.get_ages_sql
  sixties = Person.where(age: 60)
end

Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
x.report('sql') {Person.get_ages_sql}
end
```

**Whats the discrepency between:**
*0.17ms* (benchmark)
vs
*1.2ms* (reported when I run command in console)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does not do database request actually:

```
Person.where(age: 60)
```

It just build `ActiveRecord::Relation`.
You can ensure by executing next code line by line in console and watch wich line actually produce DB request:

```
relation = Person.where(age: 60); 1
relation.class.name
relation.to_a
```

But Console misleads you with "Person Load ..." because it calls additional method like `#inspect` on each code line result. And this additional method causes DB request:

```
relation = Person.where(age: 60).inspect; 1
```

And that is why your benchmark is wrong - you do test of query creation not whole DB request. It should look like:

```
def self.get_ages_sql
  Person.where(age: 60).to_a
end
```

**Added**: To get deep into Console, create

```
class ConsoleTest
  def inspect
    data.inspect
  end

  def data
    'Doing DB request'
  end

  def self.test_data
    ct = self.new
    puts 'No request yet'
    ct.data
  end
end
```

and then try in Console:

```
ct = ConsoleTest.new
```

and

```
ct = ConsoleTest.new; 1
ct.data
```

and

```
ConsoleTest.test_data
```